# Automatically calling a javascript function from php

Tags: javascript, php, html, codeigniter-4

I'm building a web app using codeigniter 4.0.4.
I want to automatically call a javascript function once whenever a certain php variable is set. But I don't know how to call the function through php or html. The code goes as follows:

**The javascript function:**

```
function my_func(error_msg)
{
    //Logic goes here
}
```

**The php:**

```
<?php if (isset($custom_error)): ?>
    <div class="mb-4 alert alert-danger">
        //Automatically call the javascript function named my_func() with parameter
    </div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: PHP runs on the server, JavaScript runs on the client. You can't call JS from PHP.

Comment: What do you want `my_func()` to do? Can't you write the function in PHP and call it when you're generating the page?

Comment: `<script>my_func('<?php echo($custom_error); ?>');</script>` probably

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<script>my_func('<?php echo $custom_error; ?>');</script>
```

its working